# How to get other field data when using values and annotate for the group in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-orm

i want to fetch 1 product for each product_type_id for specific brands.
so, I wrote this query it returns proper output but in my product model, there are other several fields like product_name, product_info, etc that are not accessible why? it only returns product_type_id & price.

```
plans_data = Product.objects.filter(brand__brand_id = brand_data_1.brand_id).values('product_type_id').annotate(min_brand_price=Min('product_price'))
```

Comment: cause you are using 'values` that converts queryset to list with specified field

Comment: I am using values to group objects please read the question and if you've solution then tell me

Comment: Please refer docs for values https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could achieve your goal in two steps,

1. use your query but add the product id
2. filter the products with in operator with all the products id of step 1

Something like this,

```
plans_id = Product.objects.filter(brand__brand_id = brand_data_1.brand_id).values('product_type_id').annotate(min_brand_price=Min('product_price'), min_id=Min('product_id'))
plans_data = Product.objects.filter(product_id__in=[plan_id['min_id'] for plan_id in plans_id])
```

Here you have some examples to combine annotates [Django Docs - Expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/expressions/)

Comment: not working it showing this error 'Min' object has no attribute 'annotate'

Comment: sorry, i have edited the answer, the idea is to keep and id besides the value you already have, so later you can get those objects by the obtain ids .. its been a while since I don't use annotate

Comment: thanks for you answer but still it throwing KeyError

Comment: thanks now it's working I changed key with name min_id

Comment: Great, glad it helps you!, thanks for the suggestion!!